# WalletConnect transactions Issue with eth_sendTransaction Popup Not Showing

Tags: javascript, metamask, wallet-connect

```js
import { WalletConnectConnector } from "@web3-react/walletconnect-connector";
```

I have used this for connecting walletconnect through QR code and used useWeb3React for connecting to wallet.
Metamask extension is working fine but not able to use walletconnect for transactions.

```js
const alchemyKey = process.env.REACT_APP_ALCHEMY_KEY;
const { createAlchemyWeb3 } = require("@alch/alchemy-web3");
var web3 = createAlchemyWeb3(alchemyKey);

const transactionParameters = [
  {
    method: "eth_sendTransaction",
    params: [
      {
        to: contractAddress, // Required except during contract publications.
        from: acct, // must match user's active address.
        data: window.contract.methods.mintNFT(acct, tokenURI).encodeABI(), //make call to NFT smart contract
      },
    ],
  },
];

await web3.eth
  .sendTransaction(transactionParameters)
  .on("receipt", (receipt) => {
    console.log(receipt, "receipt");
  })
  .on("transactionHash", (hash) => {
    console.log(hash, "hash");
  })
  .on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(err, "error");
  });
```

The above works fine with *metamask* extension but not with *Walletconnect*.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with your web3 provider. Try to get web3 provider from useWeb3React itself.

eg:

```js
const provider = connector.getProvider();
const web3 = new Web3(provider)
```

use this web3 to send transaction